# Given the number of vertices in a graph, does the formula for max number of edges it can have make intutive sense?

Tags: graph-theory

I hope I'm able to put the question clearly.

Suppose a pen costs $x$ dollars, and I buy 3 pens. So the formula for total cost is: $3x$

This makes sense, since total cost is cost of one pen times number of pens.

For a graph with n vertices, there are at the most $1+2+3....(n-1)$ edges it can have. Which is basically $(n-1)n/2$

How can I make similar intutive sense out of this formula?

Comment: Don't try to understand the number of possible edges, try to understand the _set_ of possible edges. There's one possible edge for each $2$-element subset of the set of vertices. How many $2$-element subsets of an $n$-element set are there?

Comment: That really helps. If you were to pick any two elements for an edge from the set of all vertices, first you'd have n choices, and then (n-1) choices. But this would count every edge A-B as B-A again separately too, hence divide by two. Is that right @QiaochuYuan?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following table. The top row and lefthand column list the $n$ vertices of a graph. The body of the table shows an $X$ or an $O$ for each possible edge. Notice, though that each possible edge is shown twice, once marked $X$ and once marked $O$. Specifically, if $i<k$, the possible edge between $v_i$ and $v_k$ is marked $X$ in row $i$, column $k$, and $O$ in row $k$, column $i$. Thus, to count the number of possible edges, we should count either the $X$’s or the $O$’s, but not both.

$$\begin{array}{r|c|c}
&v_1&v_2&v_3&\dots&v_{n-1}&v_n\\ \hline
v_1&-&X&X&\dots&X&X\\ \hline
v_2&O&-&X&\dots&X&X\\ \hline
v_3&O&O&-&\dots&X&X\\ \hline
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\ \hline
v_{n-1}&O&O&O&\dots&-&X\\ \hline
v_n&O&O&O&\dots&O&-
\end{array}$$

As you can see from the arrangement, the number of $X$’s (or $O$’s) is clearly $$1+2+3+\ldots+(n-1)\;.$$ On the other hand, there are $n^2$ cells in the table, of which $n$ are on the diagonal and represent impossible edges, so there are $n^2-n$ $X$’s and $O$’s altogether. We want just the $X$’s (or just the $O$’s), so we want half of that number, which is $$\frac{n^2-n}2=\frac{n(n-1)}2\;.$$ We conclude, then, that the number of possible edges is

$$1+2+3+\ldots+(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}2\;.$$

If you know about binomial coefficients, you can see this in another way: each edge corresponds to one possible choice of two of the $n$ vertices, and there are $$\binom{n}2=\frac{n(n-1)}2$$ ways of choosing two from a set of $n$ objects.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for your time in the elaborate explanation.

Comment: @GrowinMan: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can also argue by *induction*: let us have a graph with $n$ vertices and max. number of edges, then consider an (n+1)th vertex: you can draw $+n$ edges.
For one vertex there cannot be edges, and hence it is
$0+1+2+\ldots+(n-1)$ for $n$ edges.

By the way, one could also consider graphs with loops or parallel arrows, even directed graphs.. If multiple arrows allowed, then there is no upper limit on their numbers,

Answer (score 1):

Cut each edge in the middle, making two half-edges, one dangling from each endpoint. Now, each vertex can have a maximum of $n-1$ half-edges, one reaching towards each of the other vertices. $n$ vertices, each with $n-1$ half-edges attached to it, makes a total of $n(n-1)$ half-edges, or $\frac{n(n-1)}2$ whole edges.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This problem is intuitively the same as the [*handshake* problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HandshakeProblem.html) where instead of counting the max handshakes among $n$ people you want to find the max edges among $n$ vertices.

---

Suppose we have $n$ vertices labeled $v_i$,  $(i = 1,...,n)$ (the actual order is irrelevant) :

**Step 1)** Take vertex $v_1$ and connect it to all other $(n-1)$ vertices, now disgard $v_1$.

**Step 2)** Take vertex $v_2$ and connect it to all other $(n-2)$ vertices, now disgard $v_2$.

$$...$$

**Step n-2)** Take $v_{n-2}$ and connect it to all other $(2)$ vertices, now disgard  $v_{n-2}$.

**Step n-1)** Take $v_{n-1}$ and connect it to all other $(1)$ vertices, now disgard  $v_{n-1}$.

Now, notice the number of edges (in parenthesis) above we add in each step can be written as:$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$